# Screen turns off about 15 secs after resuming from sleep mode

Tags: 16.04, display, suspend, hibernate

I've noticed that in Ubuntu 16.04, when I resume from sleep mode (veille), my screen turns off about 15 secondes !
It's very irritating...

Can anybody help me?

---

My configuration :

```
Linux spectre 4.4.0-71-lowlatency #92-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
16.04 LTS
```

```
$ sudo lshw -enable pci -class display
[sudo] 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: GF119 [GeForce GT 610]
       fabriquant: NVIDIA Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       ressources: irq:318 mémoire:de000000-deffffff mémoire:d0000000-d7ffffff mémoire:d8000000-d9ffffff portE/S:e000(taille=128) mémoire:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display NON-RÉ É
       description: Display controller
       produit: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       ressources: mémoire:dd000000-ddffffff mémoire:c0000000-cfffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64)


01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)


[    28.062] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    28.064] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    28.065] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    28.065] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
```